# Perform join on multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, query-performance

I have three tables right now in a postgres DB:

```
Artists             
ID  Name        

Shows
ID  Date    Venue   Price   Is_sold Ages    Time    Multi_day   Pit     

Artists_shows       
ID  Show_id Artist_id
```

A show can have one or many artists; eventually I'm going to produce JSON for all shows that looks like this:

```
[
    {
    "bands": [
        "Domino And The Derelicts",
        "Creeper",
        "Lesbros"
    ],
    "date": "2015-12-26T08:00:00.000Z",
    "venue": "Stork Club, Oakland",
    "time": null,
    "soldOut": false,
    "pit": false,
    "multiDay": false,
    "ages": "21+",
    "price": null
    }

...]
```

Right now I'm doing this pretty inefficiently.

First, I'm running a query: `SELECT * FROM shows WHERE date >= ${date} ORDER BY date`, where `date` is today's date.

Then, I'm taking the result and running a for loop through each individual `show` that results and running this query: `SELECT artist.* FROM artist INNER JOIN artist_shows ON artist.id = artist_shows.artist_id AND artist_shows.show_id=${id}`, where `id` is each `id` from the results of the first query on the Shows table.

I'm then stitching together the results of both queries to produce the resulting JSON.

Is there a way to perform a single `JOIN` operation on my tables so that I can avoid the loop that I'm running? I assume that there might be a way to merge my existing join with my first query so that I get a table with all of the artists and all of the show details in one table. The thing that is tripping me up is the fact that a show can have many artists associated with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only return single row results so grouping in the way you are envisioning is not all that natural. There is a way, however, to use aggregate functions to combine groups and get the exact JSON result you are looking for.

```sql
SELECT
  row_to_json(all_shows)
FROM (
  SELECT
    array_agg(bands) bands,
    shows.*
  FROM shows
  JOIN (
    SELECT show_id, array_agg(artists.name)
    FROM artist_shows
    JOIN artists ON (artist_shows.artist_id = artists.id)
    GROUP BY show_id
  ) bands ON bands.show_id = shows.id
  WHERE date >= now()
) all_shows
```

Here we are using a subquery (`bands`) to group all artists names based on the show id and then join the aggregate array into the show row. Lastly you can combine all rows and return a JSON representation of the data. If you don't care to have Postgres wrap everything up into JSON then you can just use what is in the initial FROM clause.

Comment: getting an `ERROR: relation "artists" does not exist` on the `JOIN` statement.

Comment: looks like I forgot that my table was named `artist` not artist, swapping that in works

Answer (score 1):

My coding mentor suggested that I break this up into two queries because it's going to be more performant, and then to do the assembly in js:

```
buildArtistHashFromArtistsByShow(artistsByShow) {
    const showArtistsHash = {};

    for (const artist of artistsByShow) {
        if (!(artist.show_id in showArtistsHash)) {
            showArtistsHash[artist.show_id] = [artist.name];
        } else {
            showArtistsHash[artist.show_id].push(artist.name);
        }
    }

    return showArtistsHash;
}

buildParsedShows(shows, artistsHash) {
    const parsedShows = [];
    for (const show of shows) {
        const artists = artistsHash[show.id];
        parsedShows.push({
            'bands': artists,
            'date': show.date,
            'venue': show.venue,
            'time': show.time,
            'soldOut': show.is_sold,
            'pit': show.pit,
            'multiDay': show.multi_day,
            'ages': show.ages,
            'price': show.price,
        });
    }
    return parsedShows;
}

async fetchParsedShowsWithGroupedBandsAfterToday() {
    try {
        const shows = await this.db.query(`
            SELECT shows.* FROM shows WHERE date >= now() ORDER BY date
        `);


        const artistsByShow = await this.db.query(`
            SELECT artist_shows.show_id, artist.*
                FROM artist_shows
                INNER JOIN artist ON artist_shows.artist_id = artist.id
                WHERE artist_shows.show_id IN (SELECT shows.id
                    FROM shows
                    WHERE date >= now())
        `);

        const artistsHash = this.buildArtistHashFromArtistsByShow(artistsByShow);

        const parsedShows = this.buildParsedShows(shows, artistsHash);

        return parsedShows;

    } catch (error) {
        this.logger.error(error);
    }
}
```